# facebook redirect url not redirecting to intended url from facebook app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I have FB.init function to share on facebook. I am able to redirect to given redirect url through other browsers. But the same thing is not working on facebook app. It redirects me to the home url.

My function is defined as,

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      display: 'iframe',
      href: "http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/vacation_builders/" + vb_id,
      picture: imageurl,
      description: blog_description,
      title: blog_title
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response && !response.error_message) {
        console.log(response.status);
        window.location = '/congrats'
      }
      else if (response && !response.error_message == "User canceled the Dialog flow") {
        self.location.href = '/congrats'
      }
      else if (response && !response.error_message == "User+canceled+the+Dialog+flow") {
        self.location.href = '/congrats'
      }
    });
```

After i'm done sharing this image with url :- http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/vacation_builders/" + vb_id.

when I go to facebook and click on the image then everything works fine whether I click from facebook logged in from mobile browser or desktop browsers but when i go to facebook app and clicks on the link then it takes me to http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX instead of http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/vacation_builders/" + vb_id.

Comment: Does `http://54.169.27.223:9096/vacation_builders/XYZ` have the correct og:url value set?

Comment: @CBroe I don't have og:url set, 
`window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : "MY FB APP ID",
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };`
This is it what i have above my method